# Getting image path as null choosed from gallery

Tags: java, android, file-upload, gallery, image-gallery

below is my code of on activity result , here i am able to set image in recycle view and this is working fine

```
                if (data != null) {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                    int currentItem = 0;
                    while (currentItem < count) {
                        Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(currentItem).getUri();
                        currentItem = currentItem + 1;

                        Log.d("Uri Selected", imageUri.toString());

                        try {
                            arrayList.add(imageUri);
                            ImageAdapter mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageUpload.this, arrayList);
                            recycleviewShopImages.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "File select error", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (data.getData() != null) {

                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.i("TAG", "Uri = " + uri.toString());

                    try {
                        arrayList.add(uri);
                        ImageAdapter mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageUpload.this, arrayList);
                        recycleviewShopImages.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "File select error", e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

code to get filepath and post image to server

```
                 @NonNull
            private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {
          // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
            File file = FileUtils.getFile(ImageUpload.this, fileUri);


    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create (MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("shop_images[]", file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

And last here i get my image path

```
                    public class FileUtils {
private FileUtils() {} //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

/** TAG for log messages. */
private static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // Set to true to enable logging

static final String MIME_TYPE_AUDIO = "audio/*";
static final String MIME_TYPE_TEXT = "text/*";
static final String MIME_TYPE_IMAGE = "image/*";
static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO = "video/*";
static final String MIME_TYPE_APP = "application/*";

public static final String HIDDEN_PREFIX = ".";

/**
 * Gets the extension of a file name, like ".png" or ".jpg".
 *
 * @param uri Image URI
 * @return Extension including the dot("."); "" if there is no extension;
 *         null if uri was null.
 */
public static String getExtension(String uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (dot >= 0) {
        return uri.substring(dot);
    } else {
        // No extension.
        return "";
    }
}

public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {

    String path = getPath(context, uri);
    assert path != null;
    return new File(path);
}


static String nopath = "Select Video Only";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return nopath;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is <span id="IL_AD2"
 * class="IL_AD">useful</span> for MediaStore Uris, and other file-based
 * ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The context.
 * @param uri
 *            The Uri to query.
 * @param selection
 *            (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs
 *            (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return nopath;
}


private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

I dont know where i am going wrong ,because i can display image in recycle view as well but while trying to get file path it shows me null value

Comment: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A41513 this is my uri and when i try to directly pass uri to file it shows me FileNotFoundException

Comment: You mean to the File class? You cannot use the File class for an uri.

Comment: i know , i have update my file class , u can have a look now i my getting FileNotFoundException

Comment: can you please help me with refrence code bcez above mentioned discussed code is not much helpfull to understand.